# listbox, listview or datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, datagridview, listbox

- I am making a C# windows forms application to simulate a shopping
  basket. So the user can add items to the basket by entering the product name, quantity and price.
- This will also be a remove button to remove items, and and edit button
  the edit prices and quantities.
- The user will get to see their basket at all times with 4 columns,
  Item Name, Quantity, Single Price, Total Item Price.

Which would be more appropriate to use, a listbox, listview or datagridview?

Comment: Datagridview seems like the obviouse solution to me.

Comment: thats what i have used so far, but i have never used it before so i dont really know how to add,edit,remove

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to add Buttons to your control
I would use the `DataGridView` because it is easier to add Controls

`ListView` and `ListBox` don't support adding controls.
You could use them with a [ContextMenuStrip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.contextmenustrip(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: i have implemented the gridview, and successfully managed to work out how to remove rows, do you by any chance know how i can update my running total variables when an item is removed?

Comment: Can you explain a bit better what you want to achieve

Comment: i have running totals of the number of items and total price, i need to update them when items are removed

Comment: You could recalculate the total price in your removeItemEventhandler